# Building Maven project with Junit

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I made a project with RestAssured Maven. When I run it in eclipse(run as junit) it works but when I try to use `mvn package` or `mvn test` , gives me error. I want to build and run it in command line but I don't know how. I appreciate if anybody can help me with this.

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ServerTester 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ServerTester ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/alireza/Downloads/8803ASETeam4-master/ServerTester/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ ServerTester ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ServerTester ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/alireza/Downloads/8803ASETeam4-master/ServerTester/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ServerTester ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ ServerTester ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/alireza/Downloads/8803ASETeam4-master/ServerTester/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.671 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-23T22:47:00-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/429M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project ServerTester: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file /home/alireza/Downloads/8803ASETeam4-master/ServerTester/testng.xml is not a valid file
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:83)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project ServerTester: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file /home/alireza/Downloads/8803ASETeam4-master/ServerTester/testng.xml is not a valid file
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file /home/alireza/Downloads/8803ASETeam4-master/ServerTester/testng.xml is not a valid file
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There was an error in the forked process
org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file /home/alireza/Downloads/8803ASETeam4-master/ServerTester/testng.xml is not a valid file
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:509)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:380)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:990)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:824)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:722)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Team4</groupId>
  <artifactId>ServerTester</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ServerTester</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
       <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Also my project classes organization in project looks like this:
[eclipse classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVUy6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in your `surefire` plugin your are referencing a `testng` configuration file, but in your project your are using `junit`.

```
<configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```

I don't use `junit`, but maybe take a look at the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html) for setting up `surefire` with `junit`.

Answer (score 0):

The message from maven is pretty clear:

> org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file /home/alireza/Downloads/8803ASETeam4-master/ServerTester/testng.xml is not a valid file

And, as I don't see any `testng.xml` in your eclipse screenshot, I suppose it doesn't exist.

So, just remove the `suiteXmlFiles` from the surefire configuration and it should work.